# Has Mathematica derived the maximum here?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum

Suppose I define a function as

```
f[l_, a_, p_] := (l^(1 - 2*p))/(l + a)
```

Then I solve the expression for the first derivative equalling to zero for `l`

```
sol = Solve[D[f[l, a, p], l] == 0, l][[1]];
```

Now, performing the second derivative test yields

```
test = Refine[
FullSimplify[D[f[l, a, p], {l, 2}] /. sol] < 0, {0 < p <= 1/2, 
a > 0, {a, p} \[Element] Reals}]
```

This yields

```
-((2^(3 + 2*p)*p^3)/((a*(-2 + 1/p))^(2*p)*a^2)) < 0
```

(although I was expecting an answer more akin to 'True' or 'False', thus I am not entirely sure how to interpret this)

Finally, a solution should be given by

```
val = FullSimplify[f[l, a, p] /. sol]
```

In this case, we get

```
(4^p*(1 - 2*p))/(a*(-2 + 1/p))^(2*p)
```

Is this then the maximum of the function derived at the beginning?

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[f, sol, test, val]

f[l_, a_, p_] := (l^(1 - 2*p))/(l + a)

sol[a_, p_] = Solve[D[f[l, a, p], l] == 0, l][[1]]

(* {l -> (a - 2 a p)/(2 p)} *)
```

Verifying solution

```
Simplify[D[f[l, a, p], l] == 0 /. sol[a, p]]

(* True *)

test[a_, p_] = 
 Simplify[(D[f[l, a, p], {l, 2}] /. sol[a, p]) < 0, {0 < p <= 1/2, a > 0}]

(* (a (-2 + 1/p))^(2 p) > 0 *)

val[a_, p_] = FullSimplify[f[l, a, p] /. sol[a, p]]

(* 4^p (a (-2 + 1/p))^(-2 p) (1 - 2 p) *)
```

Looking at `val` for `p == 1/2`

```
val[a, 1/2]

(* Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.

Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.

Indeterminate *)
```

However, the limit is defined

```
Limit[val[a, p], p -> 1/2]

(* 1/a *)

val[a_, 1/2 | 0.5] = 1/a;
```

**EDIT:** Excluding the issue when `p == 1/2`

```
Simplify[test[a, p], {0 < p < 1/2, a > 0}]

(* True *)
```

When `p == 1/2`

```
Limit[test[a, p][[1]], p -> 1/2]

(* 0 *)

Manipulate[
 l0 = l /. sol[a, p];
 Plot[f[l, a, p], {l, Max[0, l0 - 1], l0 + 1},
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
    Tooltip[Point[{l0, val[a, p]}],
     {l0, val[a, p]}]},
  PlotRange -> All],
 {{a, 1}, 0.01, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{p, 0.25}, 0.01, 1/2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: So in this case we can only derive a maximum, which is `(4^p*(1 - 2*p))/(a*(-2 + 1/p))^(2*p)` for p strictly less than 1/2?